# How to PARTITION BY and classify certain rows into groups

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, partition

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
R_E         2020-08-20 16:37:37.693
R_S         2020-08-20 16:37:25.520
SE_E        2020-08-20 16:37:24.107
SA_E        2020-08-20 16:37:21.900
SA_S        2020-08-20 16:37:06.270
SE_R        2020-08-20 06:00:00.000
SE_P        2020-08-20 05:00:00.000
SE_R        2020-08-19 18:00:00.000
SE_P        2020-08-19 17:00:00.000
SE_S        2020-08-19 16:37:23.283
```

I want to assign a row number such that row = 1 is the last row based on the time column. However, the tricky part is how I want this grouped. First, I need the query to consider anything before the underscore as one group. So for example, there are 6 rows for 'SE'. This should be the first grouping method. Then, I want to group rows ending in '_S' and '_E' as one group and rows ending in '_P' and '_R' as another group. How do I write a row_number() function in my query such that the end result looks like this:

```
R_E         2020-08-20 16:37:37.693    1
R_S         2020-08-20 16:37:25.520    2
SE_E        2020-08-20 16:37:24.107    1
SA_E        2020-08-20 16:37:21.900    1
SA_S        2020-08-20 16:37:06.270    2
SE_R        2020-08-20 06:00:00.000    1
SE_P        2020-08-20 05:00:00.000    2
SE_R        2020-08-19 18:00:00.000    3
SE_P        2020-08-19 17:00:00.000    4
SE_S        2020-08-19 16:37:23.283    2
```

This is as far as I got:

```
select

        *
        , row_number() over(partition by substring(j.Uf_Status, 1, charindex('_', j.Uf_Status) - 1) order by j.Uf_Time desc) lastrows 

from ...
```

I can't figure out how to do the second grouping.

Comment: Why is the result for R_S = 2?

Comment: @forpas good catch. This has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a `case` expression:

```
row_number() over (partition by left(j.Uf_Status, charindex('_', j.Uf_Status) - 1),
                                (case when j.uf_status like '%[SE]' then 1
                                      when j.uf_status like '%[PR]' then 2
                                      else 3
                                 end)
                   order by j.Uf_Time desc
                  ) as lastrows
```